# Windows Batch File To Execute PHP Accessing mySQLi Database

Tags: php, batch-file

I am writing a windows batch file that needs to execute a PHP file which fetches data from a backend and inserts into mysql database.

Below is the code I used and it is working but it will open the browser.

```
@ECHO OFF
START http://localhost/test.php
```

How do I ensure that the browser is not invoked when START is executed? I have tried to put /B at the back but it not working.

I have also tried the following but it is not working at all and nothing gets inserted.

```
@ECHO OFF
php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\test.php"
```

Comment: If the browser is not supposed to open then what *is* supposed to happen?

Comment: @Jon It is suppose to fetch some data and insert into the database. Thus does not need the browser to open.

Comment: Then you should not be accessing it through a web server and a browser. Command line `php -f c:\path\to\test.php` will do what it needs to.

Comment: @Jon Yes have tried that, but I not sure for some reason it is not working, doesn't insert into database. If I use the START way, it works fine.

Comment: Then find out why it's not working and fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that php files are set up to open with your default browser, when you open the php file, it will open with that browser.

If you want to view the contents of the file in cmd instead you can use

```
type test.php
```